# Cannot import this Web Part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am new to SharePoint. There must be something i am missing out. Despite all the googling and debugging, still i get the following error:

> unable to add selected web part(s). HelloSilverlight: Cannot import this Web Part.

More than willing to provide more references. Can anyone guide me on this?

What i have on hand:
 - Windows Server 2003
 - working SharePoint Site
 - C# silverlight application named HOL.HelloWorld
 - C# silverlight application named HelloSilverlight

Answer (score 2):

As we can't see your code maybe you can compare your code with this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627341(v=office.12).aspx

To check what is going wrong in the logs check the SharePoint ULS (Unified logging service) log.
an easy way to spit through all this text is using the ULS Viewer tool by microsoft so you can filter on the errors you need:

download it here:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Answer (score 0):

Normally web part should be regular C# class library, not Silverlight one.

Please provide more information on what you actaully trying to do and what version of SharePoint you have and what steps you are performing to add the web part.

Comment: Application or class library?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually i am supposed to host a silverlight application in a web part, with Sharepoint 2007. To add a web part, i did the usual when on any C# application, such as rebuilding and deploying the solution. No problems. But now, i have to create a C# silverlight application, together with another C# application to deploy it. I do have the tutorial, if you would like to take a look @ what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: @Greg B: Yes Sir, it is an application.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the ULS logs, you may find a related error message.  Searching for the type name of the web part may help sort the wood fom the trees if you have a lot of log entries.

Commonly, this error occurs when you haven't got the SafeControl element configured in the web.config file for the web application.

If you search for the text "safe mode" in the ULS log, this usually finds the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are making some unsafe calls (e.g. run with elevated privileges) in the class constructor. Also you might need to check web.config if your web part is added as safe control.